# set an ansible variable to true if at least one row in a csv sheet column has a certain value

Tags: list, dictionary, ansible

I need to set an ansible variable to true if at least one row in a csv sheet column has a certain value (let's say "ERROR") under a certain column (let's say "lv2"), to false otherwise.

I have saved (registered) the content of the csv sheet into a variable with this task

```
- name: read my_data CSV
  community.general.read_csv:
    path: "{{ log_base_path }}/my_data.csv"
    delimiter: ;
  register: my_data
```

the content of thei variable is showed by this task

```
- name: show the variable in which is the my_data CSV content
  debug:
    var: my_data
```

whose output is

```
  localhost ok: {
    "changed": false,
    "my_data": {
        "changed": false,
        "dict": {},
        "failed": false,
        "list": [
            {
                "lv1": "ERROR",
                "attr1": "OK",
                "attr2": "OK",
                "lv2": "ERROR",
                "st_id": "75",
                "attr3": "OK"
            },
            {
                "lv1": "OK",
                "attr1": "OK",
                "attr2": "OK",
                "lv2": "OK",
                "st_id": "20",
                "attr3": "OK"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I have tryed with

```
- name: Check if any error in lv2
  set_fact:
    lv2_check_all: true
  when: "'ERROR' in my_data | map(attribute=lv2) | list"
```

but it throws this error:

localhost failed | msg: The conditional check ''ERROR' in my_data | map(attribute=lv2) | list' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional ('ERROR' in my_data | map(attribute=lv2) | list): ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object has no element AnsibleUndefined

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the fact without condition. This way the variable will always be defined

```yaml
  lv2_check_all: "{{ 'ERROR' in my_data.list|map(attribute='lv2') }}"
```

The next option is to count items that match the condition

```yaml
  lv2_check_all: "{{ my_data.list|
                     selectattr('lv2', 'eq', 'ERROR')|
                     length > 0 }}"
```

both options give

```yaml
  lv2_check_all: true
```

---

Given the file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/my_data.csv
lv1;attr1;attr2;lv2;st_id;attr3
ERROR;OK;OK;ERROR;75;OK
OK;OK;OK;OK;20;OK
```

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    lv2_check_all: "{{ my_data.list|
                       selectattr('lv2', 'eq', 'ERROR')|
                       length > 0 }}"

  tasks:

    - read_csv:
        path: /tmp/my_data.csv
        delimiter: ;
      register: my_data

    - debug:
        msg: ERROR in lv2
      when: lv2_check_all
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] ******************************************************************************

TASK [read_csv] *******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: ERROR in lv2

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```